# How can I add a custom Middleware for header validation in Rest API?

Tags: magento2, webapi

I have added 2 new `Web APIs` for the customer, but I want to add a new HTTP Header authentication with parallel to `Authorization` token.

My customer header is `AppToken`. How can I add a middleware to the Web APIs ?